# Page breaks in Dynamic Ax Reports

Tags: x++, axapta

How do you insert page breaks in Dynamic AX reports?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call `element.newPage()`.  If your report has no code on it and you want a page break before a particular section, add an `executeSection` method and call `element.newpage()` before the call to `super()`.

```
public void executeSection()
{
    ;
    element.newPage();
    super();
}
```